# Filter spark dataframe with multiple conditions on multiple columns in Pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, filter, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to implement the below SQL conditions in Pyspark

```
SELECT *
            FROM   table
            WHERE  NOT ( ID = 1
                         AND Event = 1 
                       ) 
               AND NOT ( ID = 2
                         AND Event = 2 
                       ) 
               AND NOT ( ID = 1 
                         AND Event = 0 
                       ) 
               AND NOT ( ID = 2
                         AND Event = 0 
                       )
```

What would be the clean way to do this?

Comment: If you want to created simple, i think you must define a UDF to run in your query

Comment: UDF is not necessary, it would just make the performance worse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you use *filter* or *where* function for *DataFrame API* version.

the equivalent code would be as follows :

```
df.filter(~((df.ID == 1) & (df.Event == 1)) & 
          ~((df.ID == 2) & (df.Event == 2)) & 
          ~((df.ID == 1) & (df.Event == 0)) &
          ~((df.ID == 2) & (df.Event == 0)))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're lazy, you can just copy and paste the SQL filter expression into the pyspark filter:

```
df.filter("""
               NOT ( ID = 1
                         AND Event = 1 
                       ) 
               AND NOT ( ID = 2
                         AND Event = 2 
                       ) 
               AND NOT ( ID = 1 
                         AND Event = 0 
                       ) 
               AND NOT ( ID = 2
                         AND Event = 0 
                       ) 
""")
```